# error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Edito nuevamente mi pregunta porque siento que este codigo me esta ganando al no poder encontrarle el error,
Tengo un script que lo que hace es recibir 3 valores,id , nombre y apellido de un usuario, plasma solo dos de ellos en un modal (alertsweet).
Por otro lado tengo una pagina que lo que hace es actualizar el estado del usuario y en otro tengo la grilla o cuadro que me permite dar click y generar el evento en el boton.
Ahora bien, dicho evento no solo cambia el estado usuario sino que tambien lo hace el boton.
Funciona bien cuando se desactiva al usuario pero a la hora de activarlo no ocurre lo mismo, sino mas bien que lo que hace es mostrarme este mensaje en la consola.** VM86:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**
Adjunto el código y agradezco a quien me pueda responder :)

```
if ($resultado > 0) {
                    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['idUsuarios']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['nombre']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['apellido']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['numeroDocumento']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php

                                if (($data['idUsuarios'] != 1 && $data['estado'] == 1)) {
                                    $usuarioId = $data['idUsuarios'];
                                    $usuarioNombre = $data['nombre'];
                                    $usuarioApellido = $data['apellido'];
                                ?>
                                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-4">
                                        <button onclick="promptDesactivarUsuario('<?php echo $usuarioId; ?>' ,  '<?php echo $usuarioNombre ?>','<?php echo $usuarioApellido ?>')" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"><i data-id='' role="button"><i class='bi bi-x-circle'></i> Desactivar usuario</button>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                                } else if (($data['idUsuarios'] != 1 && $data['estado'] == 0)) {

                                    $usuarioId = $data['idUsuarios'];
                                    $usuarioNombre = $data['nombre'];
                                    $usuarioApellido = $data['apellido'];
                                ?>
                                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-4">
                                    <button onclick="promptActivarUsuario('<?php echo $usuarioId; ?>' ,  '<?php echo $usuarioNombre ?>','<?php echo $usuarioApellido ?>')" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i data-id='' role="button"><i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> Activar usuario</button>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                <?php
                                                                }
                                ?>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                            ?>
                            <tbody>
                            </table>
                                </div>
```

En el script tengo lo siguiente

```
 const promptDesactivarUsuario = (id, nombre, apellido) => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Está seguro que desea desactivar al usuario '+ ' ' + nombre + ' ' + apellido + '?',
        showDenyButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: `Desactivar`,
        denyButtonText: `Cancelar`,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            fetch('../php/desactivarUsuario.php?idUsuario=' + id)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data['ok']) {
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire('No se pudo desactivar el usuario', '', 'error')
                    }
                })
        }
    })
}



const promptActivarUsuario=( id, nombre, apellido)=>{
            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Está seguro que desea activar al usuario '+ ' ' + nombre + ' ' + apellido + '?',
                showDenyButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: `Activar`,
                denyButtonText: `Cancelar`,
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    fetch('../php/activarUsuario.php?idUsuario=' + id)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data['ok']) {
                                location.reload();
                            } else {
                                Swal.fire('No se pudo activar el usuario', '', 'error')
                            }
                        })
                }
            })
        }
```

Y aca colocare solo el de activar

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./conexion.php";
$usuario = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$idUsuario = $_GET['idUsuario'];
if ($usuario) {
    $query_activar = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET estado=1 WHERE idUsuarios=$idUsuario");
    if ($query_activar) {
        // retornamos un json ok
        echo json_encode(array('ok' => true));
    } else {
        // retornamos un json error
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Tus condicionales en Javascript están mal, `data` sería un JSON, en el cual debes verificar la propiedad `ok`, prueba a ponerlo así: **`if (data.ok) {`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus condicionales en Javascript están mal, `data` sería un JSON, en el cual debes verificar la propiedad `ok` o `error`, debería ser así: **`if (data.ok) {`** pero ese código no queda acoplado, porque `data` no tendrá una propiedad `ok` cuando haya error de lógica en el código PHP. Es mejor nombrar la propiedad siempre del mismo modo, así te aseguras de que la misma siempre existirá.

Por otra parte, no entiendo por qué recargas la página, si puedes cambiar el estado, color del botón etc de forma programática, alcanzándolo por su `id` por ejemplo, de hecho, este es el sentido de `fetch` y de `ajax`, poder recibir respuestas del servidor y cambiar cosas en el cliente según esas respuestas sin tener que recargar.

Apliquemos lo dicho con respecto a acoplar el código.

#### PHP

Pondremos siempre la misma propiedad, llamada `status`, que será `true` o `false` según el caso.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./conexion.php";
$usuario = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$idUsuario = $_GET['idUsuario'];
if ($usuario) {
    $query_activar = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET estado=1 WHERE idUsuarios=$idUsuario");
    if ($query_activar) {
        // retornamos un json ok
        echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
    } else {
        // retornamos un json error
        echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
    }
}

?>
```

Convendría que hagas uso de `affected_rows` para determinar que realmente la fila se actualizó, no basta con verificar el estado de `query()` en este caso. El mismo puede ser `true` (la consulta no falló), pero eso no asegura que la fila haya sido afectada (actualizada).

### JS / HTML

Verificaremos el estado de `status` al recibir la respuesta, así acoplamos.

En el HTML daremos un `id` al botón, así lo alcanzaremos por su `id` y modificaremos lo que sea necesario en él.

El botón debe quedar así:

```
<button id="btnActivar" onclick="promptActivarUsuario('<?php echo $usuarioId; ?>' ,  '<?php echo $usuarioNombre ?>','<?php echo $usuarioApellido ?>')" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i data-id='' role="button"><i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> Activar usuario</button>
```

Y en JS, con este código, el botón debería ponerse en color verde o amarillo, según el caso. Así como cambias el color, puedes asignar una clase css que defina el estilo del botón, ponerlo en estado activado, etc, etc:

```
const promptActivarUsuario=( id, nombre, apellido)=>{
            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Está seguro que desea activar al usuario '+ ' ' + nombre + ' ' + apellido + '?',
                showDenyButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: `Activar`,
                denyButtonText: `Cancelar`,
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    fetch('../php/activarUsuario.php?idUsuario=' + id)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data.status) {
                                document.getElementById("btnActivar").style.background='#008000';
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("btnActivar").style.background='#ffff00';
                                Swal.fire('No se pudo activar el usuario', '', 'error')
                            }
                        })
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Buenas noches, primero muchas gracias por responderme, y el problema por lo cual no programo para que cambie de color e vez de actualizar la pagina es que no se manejar bien jason y javascript . Asi mismo probé lo que me dijiste pero queda fija el botón(no cambia de color el boton) , aunque si recargo la pagina de manera manual si cambia el estado dl botón

Comment: @claulia supongo que será por el reload que tienes ahí, pues no tiene sentido recargar la página. Muestra el HTML del botón que quieres modificar en la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, el html del boton seria el siguiente: <button onclick="promptActivarUsuario('<?php echo $usuarioId; ?>' , '<?php echo $usuarioNombre ?>','<?php echo $usuarioApellido ?>')" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i data-id='' role="button"><i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> Activar usuario</button>

Comment: De nuevo te vuelvo a molestar, pero realizando una inspección a la pagina cuando aprieto el boton de "activar" me sale el siguiente mensaje **VM895:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**

Comment: @claulia, como dije, el reload no tiene sentido, se ve que te intenta cargar una página HTML entera o algo así, alcanza el botón por su `id` y modifica sus propiedades. Ahora edito la respuesta para intentar explicarte.

Comment: @claulia revisa la respuesta editada. Se asigna un `id` al botón y se cambia su color de fondo de forma programática. Es algo así lo que deberías hacer, no recargar la página.

Comment: lo probe, y entendi bien el como realizar el cambio adecuado, sin embargo el problema sigue persistiendo, haciendo y mostrandome el mismo error **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Promise.then (asíncrono)
(anónimo) @ mensajesEmergente.js:34
Promise.then (asíncrono)
then @ sweetalert2@11:5
promptActivarUsuario @ mensajesEmergente.js:30
onclick @ listaUsuarios.php:58**

Comment: @claulia si en los `fetch` tú esperas un JSON, desde el servidor debes mandar un JSON, pero tú estás mandando un HTML. El problema al parecer proviene del primer bloque de código PHP que muestras en la pregunta. Sin entender todo el contexto es difícil poder ayudarte. Pero no es tan complicado, si entiendes cómo funciona `fetch`, simplemente, cuando haces una petición `fetch`, debes garantizar en el servidor que el contenido sea del tipo especificado, y los datos se reciben en la parte del `then`